# Perl crypt seemingly not working

Tags: perl, crypt

I am trying to use the crypt function to verify a user's details in database:

```
    my $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblUsers WHERE UPPER(Username)=UPPER(?) AND Password=?");
    my $count;
    $sql->execute(
        $args{login_username},
        crypt($args{login_password},$args{login_username})
        );
```

but it returns 0 rows (with the password definitely correct)

the line:

```
    $sql->execute($args{login_username},$args{login_password});
```

works perfectly.

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Is the password stored `crypt`ed in your database? (Doesn't look like it.)

Comment: How do you know it's "definitely" correct? From the Perl program, output the crypted string. Compare that, by hand, to the record in the database.

Comment: @brian: when he says the alternative `execute` line works perfectly I presume it's matching the password field unencrypted.

Comment: I try not to presume, which is why I asked. "Definitely" in debugging usually means "not really". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the password stored in the database unencrypted. To compare the values in encrypted form you need to encrypt them at the database side as well.

MySQL has an `ENCRYPT` function, so you can write

```
my $sql= $dbh->prepare(<<SQL);
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM tblUsers
WHERE UPPER(Username) = UPPER(?)
AND ENCRYPT(Password, Username) = ?
SQL

$sql->execute($args{login_username}, crypt($args{login_password},$args{login_username}));
```

but the exact syntax depends on the platform you are using.

Comment: @Borodin-`ENCRYPT` doesn't work on Windows.It returns `NULL`.